# Active Directory Copy User and his password on another domain (and forest)

Tags: active-directory, password, users, copy

Is there a way (*PowerShell* would be nice) to copy a user (I need sAMAccountName) and his password, from one domainA (forestA) to domainB (forestB).

All Active Directory servers are on LAN and this is a test environment, but if this works, gonna put script on the production.

I already know how to get a user and attributes from powershell, but I can't find anything on password.

EDIT : I must avoid trust relationship between domains

Comment: Can't be done, you'll have to grab and replicate it using a [password filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on next change or something similar

Comment: Thanks for comment. Can you give me a little bit more explanations about Password Filter ?
Otherwise, I was looking at ADMT (Microsoft's Migration Tool), and coworkers told me that I can get the hashed password. If that's true, can I just put this hash in a sort of Set-ADPassword ?

Comment: Correct, ADMT has a [password migration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974435(v=ws.10).aspx) plugin, but I don't think you can use it directly with PowerShell. A password filter is essentially a DLL implementing 3 predefined interfaces for inspecting and acknowledging password changes on a Domain Controller - LSASS passes the new password to the DLL as plaintext unicode string, but only at the time the password change occurs

Comment: Ok, that's a little bit complex for me, but I'll go deep into it and comeback if I find something good. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen